# How do I fix EACCES: permission denied, open

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I see the following error when executing
npm install -g serverless via buildspec.yml from AWS Codebuild

> storage-engine@3.0.7 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/storage-engine
> node ./compatibility/detect.js

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/storage-engine/lib/compatibility/index.js'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Comment: I just received the exact same error as you, maybe AWS has changed something?

Comment: My codebuild pipeline also just started breaking with the same error

Comment: For the time being, adding `--unsafe-perm` to the npm install command solved the problem for me. `npm install --silent --progress=false -g --unsafe-perm serverless`

Comment: `--unsafe-perm` worked for me, thank you

Comment: @VitorFreitas ```--unsafe-perm``` worked for me too, thanks

Comment: I also met the same problem.
And the same issue was reported also on AWS developer forum.
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=323762

Comment: It looks like it has been fixed. We were able to deploy without --unsafe flag

Comment: Me too. In my environment, it's also been fixed. I can deploy with doing nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

Used yarn instead of npm.

```
yarn global add serverless
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 {your node module link that is shown in the error}
```

In this case the link shown in the error is /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/storage-engine/lib/compatibility/index.js so your command would be:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/storage-engine/lib/compatibility/index.js
```